# Connecting matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to show how many endosymbionts are present in the surviving hosts as indicated by the final timestep in my hosts matrix. The corresponding columns in the endos matrix at the final timestep will be added together to represent the respective surviving hosts. If anyone has thoughts on how to show this please let me know! Here is my code so far:

```
set.seed(123)
time  <-10 
hosts <-matrix(NA,nrow=(time+1),ncol=10) 
endos <-matrix(NA,nrow=(time+1),ncol=10)
hosts[1,] <- seq(1,10)
endos[1,] <- rep(10,10)

for(tt in 1:time) {

  indexhost <- sample(1:10,size=10,replace=TRUE,prob=NULL)
  hosts[tt+1,] = hosts[tt,indexhost]

  for(indexhost in 1:10) {
    endos[tt+1,indexhost]<-rbinom(1,(2*endos[tt,indexhost]),0.5) 
  }

}
```

Comment: How do you decide a host has survive?

Comment: Indexhost samples the hosts that survive each time step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the host survivors, you can do:

```
survivors        = unique(hosts[time+1, ])
```

which will remove the duplicates in the survivor vector. Then, you can index the number of endos in the survivors. I'm assuming your dynamics for the endos is independent of the survivorship, so you can just do:

```
endosInSurvivors = endos[time+1, survivors]
```

To calculate the sum of endos by the id of the host at the last time step, you can use

```
tapply(endos[time+1, ], INDEX=hosts[time+1, ], FUN=sum) # using set.seed(1234)

 2  7 
79 38
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! What I really want to do is add the number of endos in each time step for each host and keep track of each host's number of endos. For example, if at time+1 the output for hosts was [11,]2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 and endos was[11,]13 5 8 27 20 2 16 18 5 10, I would want to add 20+16+5 for host 3 and the rest of the values for host 2. All other hosts at this time step would then have 0 endos. Thanks again for any advice!

Comment: Does it has sense in terms of modelling?